# How to have user automatically log into website (written in Django) from Chrome plugin

Tags: django, session, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome plugin, and want to have user automatically log into the website if the session is not expired. I am using Django on the server.
After reading the documentation from: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions
I know I can get the session cookie with Chrome cookie API, which has the sessionID.
Is there a way to log in user with this sessionID to Django? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I worked out this problem by firstly getting the `sessionID`, passing it to Django by AJAX;

 
In Chrome extension:

```
var sessionid = '';
chrome.cookies.get(
  {url:'http://localhost', name:'sessionid'},
  function(cookie) {
    sessionid = cookie.value;
  });
```

Get csrf token the same way; POST both to Django; If you use GET, no need for csrf_token.
Remember to set permission in manifest.json: `"http://localhost"`

In Django program:

```
sessionid = request.POST['sessionid']
s = Session.objects.get(pk=sessionid)  # From django_session table
s_data = s.get_decoded()  # s_data is a dictionary
user_id = s_data['_auth_user_id']
```

with this user id, I can get and set the user's data. I am not sure if this is safe.

Comment: This could be a lot simpler just by checking request.user.is_authenticated in your view and returning request.user.id.